# How can I extract keywords from Tridion into an Excel format?

Tags: excel, content-management-system, tridion, extract

How can I extract keywords from Tridion into an Excel format? This is for the purpose of translation of the website.

Comment: You edited away your question. What did you ask? What does the answer address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Tridion 2009: http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/exporttoexcel.aspx

If you're not, you'll have to write some sort of script (really easy) to export it to CSV or similar.

Comment: I was just going to post the same thing. Of course, this covers getting the information out, but have you considered how you would get the translations back in to the Tridion system?

Comment: Hi Sarah, extracting content from SDL Tridion is rather simple to do by anyone with >1 year Tridion experience/Core Service/WCF experience. Putting it back is a bit more complex than extracting because of the consistency rules. The easiest way to get content translated is to use the "Translation Manager" product from SDL, but I assume this was already considered and not taken (maybe for pricing considerations?) I would recommend getting in touch with Tridion Professional Services (or a partner) for a quote to build this for you, it's likely to be in the 4-5 days of work range.

Comment: @Sarah - we've just built something to perform something very similar (xlsx format only), if you want to contact me outside of this john@contentbloom.com, I'd be happy to share the code.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the audience manager then you can use the work around of exporting and importing keywords for an address book. That will export to CSV and you can import it using the same format.

However for translation purposes (localizing keywords etc.) this might be cumbersome, in that case I would use Nuno's suggestion to write a script of some sort.